# How does Orochimaru exist in all of his curse marks

Tags: naruto

Orochimaru gave quite a lot of people curse marks and i'm not sure if this is mentioned in the series but it seems like most of all those curse marks had Orochimaru living in them.

What i mean by this is: Orochimaru was able to come out of Sasuke's curse mark (during Sasuke's battle with Itachi). And also, Sasuke used Anko's curse mark to perform a reverse curse sealing Jutsu to revive Orochimaru.

Does that mean orochimaru kinda did the same thing that Voldermoth did in Harry potter? (Like seal bits of himself into all his curse seals?) but then wouldn't that mean that since he sealed pieces of himself into lots of other people then he should have lost some powers or stuff? However, Orochimaru seemed to be getting weak because his vessels couldnn't contain him. ***Was an explanation on how his curse seals work ever given? ***

I'm finding it difficult in grasping exactly how the Cursed seals that Orochimaru used work. Especially how he could be revived using any of the cursed seals. Can anyone clarify?

Answer (score 3):

Basically, your Voldemort analogy is right. He is able to put his Chakra into people through the curse mark.  This is basically putting a bit of himself in them. 
 You find out later that doing so (as well as other things) has left him weakened. This is why he wants Sasuke's body to regain his full strength.